# WSO2 ESB Message Corruption

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are a company considering using WSO2 ESB as the broker between several mission critical systems. We have been pointed to the article below which compares some solutions:

http://esbperformance.org/display/comparison/ESB+Performance

One of the claims is that WSO2 ESB corrupts messages larger than 16,384 bytes (16KB) - is this a correct statement? As the article was written by a competing company we are under impression that there is some configuration flaw or some oversight as this looks like a major bug.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, you are correct in saying that the performance benchmark was carried out by competitors of the WSO2ESB product line. There are a couple of observations masquerading as corruption issues, but only half of this may have any merit. The issue related to XSLT corruption is an erroneous conclusion, the tested configuration was missing semantics and errors resulting from this cannot be attributed to message corruption.

The issue in question related to corruption of messages larger than 16K was only a problem with a non-default customised configuration that enabled a feature known as Streaming XPath, which is used to enhance performance in XPath scenarios. While there was a real issue here, this was never a default configuration and has not really affected the thousands of real deployments of WSO2 ESB out there. Streaming XPath was stabilised in the recently released WSO2ESB 4.8.0. The WSO2 ESB continues to be the fastest open source ESB. Case studies like: http://wso2.com/casestudies/ebay-uses-100-open-source-wso2-esb-to-process-more-than-1-billion-transactions-per-day/ show WSO2 ESB's worth in high volume and high performance scenarios.